# Create and post cookie from a HTML button

Tags: javascript, php, variables, button, cookies

In my page i have three php variables.
Each variable has his own button in the page

```
<article>
</p>Some infor</p>
?php echo $hotelName0;?>
<a title="" href="details.php">DETAILS</a>
</article>
<article>
</p>Some infor</p>
?php echo $hotelName1;?>
<a title="" href="details.php">DETAILS</a>
</article>
<article>
</p>Some infor</p>
?php echo $hotelName2;?>
<a title="" href="details.php">DETAILS</a>
</article>
```

Ho can i create a cookie from the selected article and post its correspodent variable ($hotelNamex)
Can this be done with php cookies ?
Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Technically yes, but why !!! One better way is to use 'GET' or 'Post' request parameters ex `details.php?id=$hotelName0` and in the PHP file you can read it by `$_REQUEST["id"]`

Comment: To back up @AhmedDaif; indeed why? You can pass the variable as a `get` in the query string of `details.php`.

Comment: `<a title="" href="details.php?hotel=<?php echo $hotelName2; ?> ">`